# Do we "learn byheart something" or "byheart something"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, indian-english

Do we "learn byheart something" or "byheart something"?

> **We learn by heart something and produce it Verbatim**.

Some Indian professors of English are using **Byheart** as a verb.

Is **byheart** used as a verb in native English speaking countriies and is it acceptable as Idiomatic English there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Byheart" as single word is restricted to Indian dialects of English, and so should be considered non-standard (ie incorrect) when speaking British or American English.

The phrase "by heart" is quite common, but cannot be used as a verb.

> You should learn the play by heart.

If someone told me to "You should byheart the play" I would probably be able to guess the meaning. But I would find it very odd.